# Ajax Request Payload contains unexpected encoding

Tags: c#, ajax, datatables, payload

I am trying to pass a variable via Ajax to the retrieve data to fill a DataTable. I'm yet to find an explanation as to why, but my Ajax payload is resulting in a strange encoding with a combination `%` and `=` symbols along with some random characters. I've played around with the contentType and the way in which I use the JSON.stringify() but neither correct the unexpected output I am experiencing.

**Javascript Ajax request:**

```
var group = { groupId: 123456789 }
...
"ajax": {
    type: 'POST',
    url: window.SiteRootURL + 'Group/GetGroup',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(group),
    "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
         notfiy({ status: "Error", message: thrown }, 'error');
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetGroup(Int32 groupId)
{
    // do something
}
```

**Ajax Request Payload:**

```
0=%7B&1=%22&2=g&3=r&4=o&5=u&6=p&7=A&8=r&9=t&10=i&11=f&12=a&13=c&14=t&15=I&16=d&17=%22&18=%3A&19=1&20=2&21=3&22=4&23=5&24=6&25=7&26=8&27=9&28=%7D
```

**Expected Ajax Request Payload:**

```
{groupId: 123456789}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: try "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: @Bindrid already tried that one, no luck unfortunately

Comment: did you verify window.SiteRootURL is what is expected?

Comment: what happens if you pass {groupId:  "123456789"}

Comment: I have been using datatables and c# for several years, never seen anything like that

Comment: @Bindrid the window.SiteRootURL is working fine, changing the integer to a string doesn't change the output.

Comment: This guy has: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22727/posting-json-via-ajax-results-in-garbled-request-payload

Comment: do you have the [HttpPost] tag on your  public ActionResult GetGroup(Int32 groupId)
{
    // do something

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the AJAX reqeust as `console.log(JSON.stringify(group))` outputs `{"artifactId":123456789}` which indicates that the data itself is not the issue.

Comment: Yes `[HttpPost]` is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is directly related to [DataTables](https://datatables.net). In the Ajax request, `ajax.data` does not accept a string. In order to post JSON data you must return the string in a function. The below is an example from the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function ( d ) {
      return JSON.stringify( d );
    }
  }
} );
```